# Why is my join giving me way too many results?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join

I have:

```
  SELECT  dv.VariableID ,
            ds.DataSourceID ,
            p.DataVariableDataSourceParamId ,
            p.ParamCode ,
            p.ParamDisplayName ,
            p.DVDSParamControlType ,
            p.DependentOnDVDSParamId ,
            pv.ParamValue
    FROM    dbo.DataVariable dv
            INNER JOIN dbo.DataVariableDataSource ds ON dv.DataSourceId = ds.DataSourceID
            INNER JOIN dbo.DataVariableDataSourceParam p ON ds.DataSourceID = p.DataSourceId
            INNER JOIN dbo.DataVariableDataSourceParamValue pv ON p.DataVariableDataSourceParamId = pv.DataVariableDataSourceParamId
    WHERE   dv.VariableID = @vid
    ORDER BY dv.VariableID
```

When I just have the first two joins, I get what I want: 6 results. When I add the third, I get 660. I just want the ParamValue for the 6 records from the first 2 joins and I can't seem to figure out why this is breaking. I'm on my 12th hour of coding and I'm sure this is insanely obvious, but I could use a hand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the table DataVariableDataSourceParamValue look like?

Comment: Show us the schema, at least for `DataVariableDataSourceParamValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be because you have numerous rows in your `pv` table that match on `DataVariableDataSourceParamId`

You can verify by adding a `SELECT DISTINCT`. You may need to clean that table up or keep the distinct

However, the distinct will only help if `pv.ParamValue` is the same for all, otherwise you are rightfully getting more matches as what is happening is that you are finding all the matches for `DataVariableDataSourceParamId` and displaying them. If all those matches are the same value, then the distinct will indeed help, though

Comment: You were right. I had to use an AND on the join to get what I wanted. 13th hour of coding just started - the mind is not quite working at full capacity.